# Render component in jsx based on async function returning boolean

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an html element to render based on the return value of an async/await function. I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Below is the async function being called

```
const isAuthorized= async() => {
  const isAuthorized = await Promise.resolve().then(() => false);
  console.log("isAuthorized =", isAuthorized);
  return isAuthorized;
}
```

Below is the jsx:

```
const ComponentName= () => {
    return (
        <div>
            {Promise.resolve(isAuthorized()).then(res => {res ? <p>User is authorized</p> : <p>User is not authorized</p>})}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentName;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: Isn't just `{ isAuthorized() ? <p>User is authorized</p> : <p>User is not authorized</p>}` working?

Comment: nope, it renders the first regardless if the function returns true or false. I believe this is because the function requires an async call, and the virtual dom renders it before the function is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a state in your component to track whether your user is authorized or not. Then you can use a `useEffect` hook to check the status. Your component should render (and re-render) based on the state change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/promiseinuseeffect-do22b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

It is imposible in React.

1) Try use async/await

2) Make you preparation data in useEffect ( componendDidUpdate )

```
const ComponentName = () => {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = setState(undefined);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        (async function() {
            if (!isAuth) {
                const result = await isAuthorized();
                setIsAuth(result);
            }
        })();
    }, []);
    const text = isAuth ? 'User is authorized' : 'User is not authorized';
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: it says setState is not recognized, and if I use `this.setState`, I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using state

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            isAuthorized: false
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const isAuthorized = await Promise.resolve().then(() => false);
        this.setState({isAuthorized: isAuthorized});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isAuthorized ? <p>User is authorized</p> : <p>User is not authorized</p>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, I don't think it's secure having a variable like this as state on the dom?